# Counting the occurrences of boolean between two equal variables?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to count the numbers of occurrences that appears `True` in an array between two variables when the position of `1` in the variable is equal to the position `1` in the other variable, and so forth.

I have tried:

```
public class another_test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] x = new String[]{"win", "win", "lose"};
        String[] y = new String[]{"win", "lose", "lose"};
        int z=0;
        if(x.equals(y)) {
            z++;
        }
        System.out.println(z);  //output = 0
    }
```

The answer I should be getting is `2`, how to solve for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] x = new String[]{"win", "win", "lose"};
    String[] y = new String[]{"win", "lose", "lose"};
    int z=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length && i < y.length; i++) {
        if(x[i].equals(y[i])) {
            z++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(z);
}
```

Another approach (functional):

```
    long z = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(x.length, y.length))
            .filter(i -> x[i].equals(y[i]))
            .count();

    System.out.println(z);
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lime you have two arrays of String. You need to compare elements from both array of same index(whether they are similar or not).

You can use simply use for loop where `i` will work as index and it should be less than both array's length.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] x = new String[]{"win", "win", "lose"};
    String[] y = new String[]{"win", "lose", "lose"};
    int noOfTrueOccur=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length && i < y.length; i++) {

        //here you are comparing actual String content
        if(x[i].equals(y[i])) {
            noOfTrueOccur++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(noOfTrueOccur); //Output=2
}
```

This is simple way to do it. There are other ways also.